# Converting timestamp(string) to date(dddd-mm-yy) in presto

Tags: presto, trino

I have a timestamp value in a varchar column. the value looks like below.

`2020-10-31T23:36:03.000+0000`

I want to convert this to below for using it in my query filter.

`2020-10-31`

I tried using date_parse and split_part:

`SELECT date_parse('2020-06-30T17:17:35.000+0000','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s:%f') as xy`
and

`where cast(split_part('2020-06-30T17:17:35.000+0000', ' ', 1) as date) >= date '2020-06-30'`

Both return error saying:

`presto error: Invalid format: "2020-06-30T17:17:35.000+0000" is malformed at "T17:17:35.000+0000"`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

Using this solved my problem

`cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2020-06-30T17:17:35.000+0000') as DATE)  >= date '2020-06-30'`